# Define allowed includes in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to build a project in `ANSI-C` on `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]` with `msbuild` version `Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 15.1.1012.6693`

I get to compile everything correct, with the setup shown below.

---

### Project Strcuture

The projectfolder is structed like this:

```
- projectfolder
    - a.vcxproj
    - main.c
    - main.h
    - other.c
    - other.h
    - test.c
    - test.h
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "main.h"
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    test_printf();
    return 0;
}
```

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

#endif // !MAIN_H_
```

other.c

```
#include "other.h"

#ifdef dummy
int some_number = 3;
#endif // dummy
```

other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H_
#define OTHER_H_

#define dummy

#ifdef dummy
extern int some_number;
#endif // dummy

#endif // OTHER_H_
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "test.h"

extern int test_printf(void) {
    printf("Hello from test.c");
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

extern int test_printf(void);

#endif // !TEST_H_
```

The build script `a.vcxproj` looks like this (Generated by `Visual Studio 2017 Community` and then adapted to my needs in an editor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
          <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
          <Platform>Win32</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <VCProjectVersion>15.0</VCProjectVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{25F5E5F8-5F52-4BFC-A822-766DCFC1F5BA}</ProjectGuid>
        <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
        <RootNamespace>a</RootNamespace>
        <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.15063.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
        <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
        <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
        <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
        <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />

    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
        <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    </ImportGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
        <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
        <OutDir>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
        <IntDir>bin\$(Configuration)\obj\</IntDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
        <ClCompile>
            <PrecompiledHeader>
            </PrecompiledHeader>
            <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
            <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
            <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
        </ClCompile>
        <Link>
            <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
        </Link>
        <BuildLog>
            <Path>bin\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName).log</Path>
        </BuildLog>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Include="other.c">
            <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
            <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Include="test.c">
            <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
            <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Include="main.c">
            <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
            <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />

</Project>
```

---

** This compiles fine without warnings/rrors to a *.exe **

---

### What I Want To Achieve

But I want to spefcify for each object file that gets generated (main.obj, other.obj and test.obj) the sources the compiler is allowed to use fot the compile step.

If I change the `<ItemGroup>` of each to this (every to be generated *.obj files, gets the *.c files it should use for the compile step:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="other.c">                   <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
        <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
        <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="test.c;other.c">            <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
        <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
        <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.c;other.c;test.c">     <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
        <DisableLanguageExtensions Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</DisableLanguageExtensions>
        <CompileAs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">CompileAsC</CompileAs>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>
```

I then get following compiler and linker warnings:

InitializeBuildStatus:

```
  "bin\Debug\obj\a.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird erstellt, da "AlwaysCreate" angegeben wurde.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(937,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files
 with the name of other.c will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are other.c, other.c, o
ther.c. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(937,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more files
 with the name of test.c will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are test.c, test.c.
```

Link:

```
bin\Debug\obj\other.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
bin\Debug\obj\other.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
bin\Debug\obj\test.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
```

Build succeeded:

```
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(WarnCompileDuplicatedFilename Ziel) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(937,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more fil
es with the name of other.c will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are other.c, other.c,
 other.c. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(937,5): warning MSB8027: Two or more fil
es with the name of test.c will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to an incorrect build result.  The files involved are test.c, test.c. [C
:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->

  (Link Ziel) ->
  bin\Debug\obj\other.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
  bin\Debug\obj\other.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]
  bin\Debug\obj\test.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored [C:\Users\user\Desktop\question\a\a.vcxproj]

    5 Warnung(en)
    0 Fehler
```

---

Is there a way in in `msbuild` to achive what I like to do: Telling msbuild for each source file what it allowed to use for the compile step?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve: you want one .obj with the compiled source from other.c, one .obj with the source from other.c *and* test.c, etc, and then you want to link those together? Why would you compile one .c file more than once and what do you expect the linker to do with that? In any case, CLCompile does not define 'compile steps', it lists items to compile and what you wrote is basically equivalent to `<ClCompile Include="other.c;test.c;other.c;main.c;other.c;test.c"/>`.. Btw also no need to duplicate all the options if they are the same for each file.

Comment: I do not want to compile a *.c-file more than once. Maybe I totally misunderstood what the `<ClCompile Include="file.c">` does. I want to specfiy to the compiler which files he is allowed to take to generated the object file from, like in `make`, where I can say: `main.o: main.c main.h other.c other.h test.c test.h`. Does this clearfiy what I want to achieve.

Comment: Not sure.. Dependency management is different for msbuild than for make, and so is tracking changes for compiler input (e.g. the header files) and comiler and linker are integrated on a somewhat higher level. As such there is no need to specify what the intermediate main.o depends on, you specify compiler inputs and that's it, rest is figured out automatically. For the use case you show I also don't see anything requiring you to use anything more complicated than the generated file (which could be shortened to `<ClCompile Include="other.c;test.c;main.c">` or even `<ClCompile Include="*.c">`)